# How to count 0 value by column and calculate the percentage. Power BI, DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

Hi I would like to ask you some help.

So i have a problem, i want to count the 0 value then calculate the percentation by Site Name. here is my data model

[image]

how to count the 0 value if i want to read it from left to right (by column) ?

thank you so much for the help!

Comment: May I know which columns 0 value you want to count? Can you provide like an example of what you are trying to achieve? Thanks.

Comment: i want to count the 0 Value by Site Name, for example i would like to count how many 0 Value in Site Name APK

Comment: did you want this displayed in a calculated column or in a measure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to count number of 0s in the 4 columns based on Site Name. You will need to create a calculated table like below

```
CalculatedTable = SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(
                                    'YourTable'[Site Name],
                                    "Reach Truck",CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('YourTable'),'YourTable'[Reach Truck]=0),
                                    "CBT/FL",CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('YourTable'),'YourTable'[CBT/FL]=0),
                                    "PM",CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('YourTable'),'YourTable'[PM]=0),
                                    "HPJ",CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('YourTable'),'YourTable'[HPJ]=0)
                                )
```

Hope it helps.